# Karate 1.0.1 NullPointerException when sending a number in a PUT request

Tags: java, karate

Going from karate 0.9.5 to 1.0.1 I found that sending a PUT request with a number returns a java.lang.NullPointerException.

e.g.

---

In v0.9.5 this was working:

```
Given path 'v1', 'users'
And request 7
When method PUT
Then status 400
```

Now it returns a NullPointerException:

[image]

---

To reproduce :

```
  @PutTest
  Scenario: Put Test
    Given url  'https://www.google.com/'
    And request 7
    When method PUT
    Then status 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a string please:

```
And request '7'
```

Comment: I have a separate test for strings. This is to test the endpoint, to verify what happens if a number is sent rather than an object. Is this no longer possible in version 1.0.1?

Comment: @bshek as per the HTTP spec it is *always* a string, look it up if you want. karate was performing a convenience for you converting it to a string, which I've anyway gone ahead and fixed for the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/1a830bee8bc164bac061bd1f1a4cf5e94dcfcd91 - so in my opinion, your test for number is a waste of time. you are welcome to contribute code and "fix" karate if you still feel so